# Who should our beta moderators be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

I just saw [a post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) from the stackoverflow blog with the following suggestion: "If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now!" I searched to see if there was such a post here, and didn't find one. So here we go.

That same blog post lists desirable qualities for moderators to have:

> 1. Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> 2. Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> 3. Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> 4. Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

And bonus points for:

> 1. Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> 2. [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
> 3. Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

If there's someone you would like to nominate as a moderator pro tem for chess.SE, please post an answer below giving the nominee's name (linked to his or her user profile on main and meta). **Each nominee should appear in a separate answer.** Self-nomination is okay, *even encouraged* (since a young site means relatively limited knowledge of other users). If you do nominate a 3rd party, he or she will need to accept the nomination by editing the answer to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 12):

[image: profile for Daniel δ on Stack Exchange]

- Clearly understands SE
- [Votes the most](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all) of any user on Chess.SE
- [Edits the most](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) of any user on Chess.SE
- And per Daniel δ - "[I would very much like being a moderator here](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89/moderators-pro-tem/93#comment104_91)"

**Edit** from Daniel δ - further info:

I have but one year of experience in SE to boast of - I am still a learner, but aspire to be an experienced learner.

I have been active in the SE network long enough to amass some credentials: as of now, at [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10041/daniel): 27K rep, 129 questions, 434 answers, 6530 votes, 1807 edits, 303 helpful flags. Among my hard-earned [badges](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10041/daniel?tab=badges) there: [Fanatic](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/23), [Convention](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/67), [Proofreader](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/100), [Reviewer](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/106), [Archaeologist](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/101), [Research Assistant](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/109), [Deputy](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/75/deputy), [Pundit](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/24), [Epic](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/26), and [Sportsmanship](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/61) (and now [Yearling](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/52/yearling)!), not to mention [Electorate](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/28) and [Copy Editor](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/33). And though I have, as @Ed pointed out, slowed down at English.SE, I still have [2nd place in voting](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all).

I believe I will be able to spend the time necessary to moderate here during this site's beta. It's not as time-consuming as English.SE was, even when I wasn't a mod. Also, I think I'll be pretty safe with Ed Dean. I have the idea that he'll be a pillar to this site in terms of moderation. And with a third moderator (Andrew?), we'll be ready to roll!

*After* all that, I think it's only fair to let everyone know I'm only 16. Be that as it may, I'll try my very best not to let that fact give anyone cause to look down on me. I believe I can do the job and do it well, especially given the example of [this moderator](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/100/waiwai933) at English.SE, whose decisions and activity I have grown to respect, though he's just about my age.

My chess ability is not very extensive (rated about 1300 by online play, mostly 5-10 min blitz games), due in large part to the fact that my only chess education has come from playing with friends and reading the dozen or so books on chess that I own.  At this point I'm not sure whether I want to make chess anything more than a hobby, but whatever the case may be, I will always find enjoyment in it, and I will always welcome fresh knowledge of it.

Anything else you want to know about me will probably be found if you click around a bit in [my profile](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/86/daniel).

Comment: @blunders I think you can make the post community wiki so that Daniel can edit it directly too.
+1 for Daniel!

Comment: +1 for Daniel :)

Answer (score 11):

[Ed Dean](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/167/ed-dean) - I see a lot of high quality, well-thought-out answers from you, and based on your proactive meta participation and level-headed, consistent input (not to mention your in-depth understanding of chess), I think it would be a benefit to the site for you to be a moderator.

**Ed's Edit:** I'm a regular visitor to [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), though I go mostly to read, and contribute infrequently. A little while ago I was on that site, and found myself thinking that a stackexchange for chess should be created. I was even about to get geared up for an Area 51 proposal, but I went looking and, lo and behold, this place had just come out of private beta. So I definitely think chess.SE is a great idea, and I'd like to see it thrive. I'd be happy to do some moderating to help that along.

Comment: Seriously, Ed, you're the only one I'd like to venture to nominate currently, since your interest in the future of this site is pretty plain.  @Andrew, maybe others, could be an excellent moderator too, but I don't know what he thinks about the matter.  If you see this, Andrew, could you give your thoughts?  Nominate yourself if you want the position/title/responsibility/privilege of being a moderator; I'd back you up, and so would many others, I'm sure.

Comment: thanks for the kind thoughts.  I'd obviously be happy to, and I'd love to see the site succeed, but I'm not sure I've participated in SE enough to do a good job.  I've mainly only lurked on StackOverflow and listened to the podcasts.
+1 to Ed Dean too!

Comment: Ed and Andrew will both make great moderators.  I hope to help grow the site in anyway I can.

Comment: @xaisoft The same goes for you - I don't know if you are interested in being a moderator, and also I haven't yet seen evidence of much behind-the-scenes participation from you - but I haven't seen much of anything yet!  I see you've been a steady contributor to the site, but I don't know much else about you.  If you'd like to nominate yourself, please do so!

Comment: Thanks for the votes of confidence; I'll throw my hat in the ring. Daniel has prodigious experience over at English.SE, but his profile mentions a sort of "retirement" from SE, so I won't nominate him. And I can't tell from the comment of xaisoft whether he's interested in moderating or not. So I just nominated @Andrew in another answer.

Comment: @EdDean That "retirement" is kind of spotty - I had originally intended it to be a retirement from English, since I was spending way too much time there (4 hrs a day sometimes).  I just don't know, for myself, whether I could conscientiously take up the responsibility.  I realize that being a pro tem mod here won't be anywhere near as time-consuming as being a regular mod at English.SE.  I'll consider it; for now, we'll just see if anyone else steps up.  If not, you may be seeing my name in one of these posts.

Comment: @EdDean I would very much like being a moderator here, though - that's not an issue :)

Comment: @Daniel δ: Awesome, since I believe you'd make a great mod. Just posted you as a [nominee](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/a/93/38), cheers!

Comment: @EdDean - I wouldn't mind being a moderator, but the one thing against me is time.  I don't believe I will have the time even though Daniel said it shouldn't be too time consuming.

Comment: @xaisoft  I don't have my heart set on it, as you can probably tell from some of my comments.  If you think you can do it, I don't want you to hesitate nominating yourself.  I see that you've contributed more than I have to the site.  I'm mostly stepping in here because 1) no one else has so far spoken up (till now) and 2) I know I could do it.  But if you think you could, I wouldn't mind remaining a "power user", so you could be the third mod. :)  (I think only three pro tem mods are ever chosen.  I'll ask on Meta.SO.)

Comment: [Apparently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134978/164012) there can be four, if we request it.  If @xaisoft *and* I are both kinda part-time, we could both be mods.  Just a thought.

Comment: I can do part time if it is allowed.

Answer (score 10):

Since [Andrew](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/12/andrew) expressed interest, though hesitance to nominate himself, in a comment to Daniel's answer, I am putting his name forth. When I found the site shortly after the private beta had ended, Andrew had already distinguished himself with many fine contributions, and his reputation reflected that other users agreed. He's also raised (and responded to) various issues on the meta side of things, so he seems like a very natural choice.

---

After giving this some thought, I would like to accept the nomination.  I'm very excited about the site, and I really want it to succeed and grow.  My only concern is that I'm not very familiar with the Stack Exchange platform beyond listening to the [podcasts](http://blog.stackoverflow/category/podcasts).  I am more than willing to learn and take constructive criticism, however.

In terms of chess, I'm a 2100 player from Massachusetts.  I play in quite a few OTB tournaments, and play blitz/bullet online from time to time as well.  My [careers page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ahoy) has some information about me although nothing about my chess background.  I started playing competitive chess freshman year of high school on my school's chess team.  My senior year I started playing serious OTB tournaments, and my USCF rating rose to roughly 1500.  In college, I again found time to play slow tournaments, and my rating has improved to its current level (http://main.uschess.org/datapage/ratings_graph.php?memid=12846607).

In terms of moderation, I've visited the site every day, and it's usually open in a tab on whatever computer I'm using.  (As is the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3293/chess)!)  My personal opinion is that questions should be of a high quality, and so far I've tried to edit or close questions that might not be good enough for the site (in terms of too localized, too easy, etc).

Ultimately I'd like to see more advanced chess questions as well as some of the more complicated questions that TD's face.  I've been mentioning the site everywhere I can, and I'm looking forward to seeing what happens down the road!

Comment: "Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 42 minutes."

Comment: +1. Good Luck Andrew